# MS SQL - Get Before / After Specific Rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have this table in SQL. Columns F and G are blank in SQL but I have shown how I would like to fill them out in this table.

When the column "Valid" is True, I want to capture the first row before it starts for all the rows until the last e.g. it goes false. Then populate the Units value in the Pre Units column. Then when it has the last row I want it to populate the "Post Units" column. Any idea on how to do this with MS SQL please?

[Table Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW9IQ.png)

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SODATA](
    [PKID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NULL,
    [ProductCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Units] [float] NULL,
    [Valid] [bit] NULL,
    [PreUnits] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [PostUnits] [decimal](18, 5) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (400, N'2019-04-01', N'Product1', 306, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (480, N'2019-04-08', N'Product1', 471, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (561, N'2019-04-15', N'Product1', 248, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (642, N'2019-04-22', N'Product1', 87, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (725, N'2019-04-29', N'Product1', 304, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (804, N'2019-05-06', N'Product1', 234, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (892, N'2019-05-13', N'Product1', 131, 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (980, N'2019-05-20', N'Product1', 137, 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (1070, N'2019-05-27', N'Product1', 491, 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (1158, N'2019-06-03', N'Product1', 474, 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (1245, N'2019-06-10', N'Product1', 424, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (1333, N'2019-06-17', N'Product1', 312, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (1420, N'2019-06-24', N'Product1', 483, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (1510, N'2019-07-01', N'Product1', 378, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (1598, N'2019-07-08', N'Product1', 301, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (1684, N'2019-07-15', N'Product1', 67, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (1784, N'2019-07-22', N'Product1', 153, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (1878, N'2019-07-29', N'Product1', 232, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (1974, N'2019-08-05', N'Product1', 145, 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (2069, N'2019-08-12', N'Product1', 84, 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (2163, N'2019-08-19', N'Product1', 231, 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (2257, N'2019-08-26', N'Product1', 454, 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (2351, N'2019-09-02', N'Product1', 297, 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (2445, N'2019-09-09', N'Product1', 274, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (2539, N'2019-09-16', N'Product1', 331, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (2633, N'2019-09-23', N'Product1', 348, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (2727, N'2019-09-30', N'Product1', 220, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (2821, N'2019-10-07', N'Product1', 300, 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (2915, N'2019-10-14', N'Product1', 132, 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (3009, N'2019-10-21', N'Product1', 68, 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SODATA] ([PKID], [Date], [ProductCode], [Units], [Valid], [PreUnits], [PostUnits]) VALUES (3102, N'2019-10-28', N'Product1', 450, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
```

Comment: Images of data doesn't help us help you. Take the time to post the data in a consumable format; preferable DDL and DML statements.

Comment: To be clear, you're defining before/after based on the `Date` column? Or the `PKID` column? I know both appear to define the same order in your picture but it's best to be clear which column(s) you're using to define the order.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it will be based on Product Code then Date.

Comment: @Larnu my apoligises, I have updated the question with data you can import into SQL now.

Comment: `[Date] [nvarchar](50) NULL,` Nope - just start over. You store DATES in a DATE datatype, not as a string

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake on my part. It is stored as a date.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CTE ([Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)), [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

The code, after the inserts on the question, is:

```
;WITH mark_changes as (
    select
    PKID,Date,ProductCode,Units,Valid,
    case when ISNULL(Valid,0)<>ISNULL(LAG(Valid,1,2) OVER(order by PKID),0) then 1 else 0 end as Changed
    from SODATA
)
SELECT
PKID,Date,ProductCode,Units,Valid,
case when Valid=1 and Changed=1 then LAG(Units,1,0) OVER(order by PKID) else NULL end as PreUnits,
case when Valid=1 and ISNULL(LEAD(Valid,1) OVER(order by PKID),0)=0 then Units else NULL end as PostUnits
from mark_changes
order by PKID
```

And you can see this example on DB Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4644ce613eadbcf516473fb5f80bcffa).

Answer (score 0):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3e35b5962e43c1466ee85b6cc08316f9 lptr posted as a comment and works wonderfully thanks.

```
update x
set preunits = newpreunits,
postunits = newpostunits
from
(
select *, 
  max(prvunits) over(partition by productcode, grpid) as newpreunits,
  max(nxtunits) over(partition by productcode, grpid) as newpostunits
from
(
select *, sum(addme) over(partition by productcode order by date) as grpid
from
(
select *, 
  case when valid=1 and lead(valid) over(partition by productcode order by date) is null
  then lead(units) over(partition by productcode order by date) 
  end as nxtunits,
  
  case when valid=1 and lag(valid) over(partition by productcode order by date) is null
  then lag(units) over(partition by productcode order by date) 
  end as prvunits,
  
  case when 
    (valid=1 and lag(valid) over(partition by productcode order by date) is null)
    or
    (valid is null and lag(valid) over(partition by productcode order by date) = 1)
  then 1 else 0 end as addme
from sodata
) as agg
) as g
) as x
where newpreunits is not null
or newpostunits is not null
```